# Cypress - how to wait until application is ready?

Tags: cypress

I want to wait until the application that Cypress tests against is ready. This code doesn't seem to do the job - any ideas?

```
before(() => {
    cy.request('GET', baseUrl, { failOnStatusCode: false, timeout: 60000 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just using `cy.visit()`? It will wait for 60 seconds (it can be increased), for the page to load.

If you have to use request, then I would recommended using [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until). With it, you can wait for almost anything. For your case, it would be:

```
cy.waitUntil(() => { cy.request('GET', baseUrl, { failOnStatusCode: false, timeout: 60000 }).its('isOkStatusCode')});
```

The code above will wait till the request ends with success code. I suggest, that you extend the timeout, because application can take some time to start:

```
cy.waitUntil(() => { cy.request('GET', baseUrl, { failOnStatusCode: false, timeout: 60000 }).its('isOkStatusCode')},{ timeout: 60000 });
```